# How to render views based on user role on Rails 5.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am currently working on a Rails 5.1 application that has two different User roles: "Admin" and "Customer".
(I am storing the roles in a column named "role" #string on the User's table).

I am looking for the most efficient way to render different views based on the User Role. e.g.

- If a user with the user.role = "Customer" logs in, I would like to render
  customer#index
- If a user with the user.role = "Admin" logs in, I would like to render
  admin#index

Right now the route root is "admin#index". Is there a way to change the root route based on the role of the current user?

Any tips for the most efficient way of rendering different views based on user role will be appreciated! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify the `after_sign_in_path_for` route for a resource.  So

application_controller.rb

```
....

def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  if resource.role == "Customer"
    customers_path (or whatever the name of the path is in your routes)
  elsif resource.role == "Admin"
    admins_path (same here, whatever the name of the path is in your routes)
  else
    super
  end
end

....
```

There are a bunch of methods like this that you might find useful digging through, for this specific one https://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/Devise/Controllers/Helpers:after_sign_in_path_for, or for all options https://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/Devise/Controllers/Helpers.

Comment: Thank you! Right now my route root is admin#index, is there a way to make it dynamic based on the user role? E.g. admin#index for Admin users and customer#index for Customer users. Or should I have a different root path?

Comment: Well if the controllers are namespaced yes, then you could set the admin root and customer root and so on, but if not then I think you have to redirect.